# Hide a Segmentation Fault Perl 5.8.8 with Threads and Perl TK

Tags: multithreading, perl, segmentation-fault, tk-toolkit

I've written a GUI using Perl TK and Threads.  Everything works wonderfully until the program is exited.  At this time I get a segmentation fault.  I believe I'm managing my threads as well as I can and that the segmentation fault is simply due to threads in Perl version 5.8.8.  I know this version is very old, but I cannot update because of work.  So, my question is, can I simply hide the segmentation fault somehow?  Or, is there a surefire way to completely clean up the threads?  I don't think my code is relevant due to the nature of the problem, but here is how I end my threads:

```
my $thr = threads->create(\&worker);  ##this is created before any TK objects

sub worker {

 while($run){
  ##do thready-stuff here
 }

}

sub OnExit {
 $run=0;
 exit 0;
}
```

Where $run is a shared variable and &OnExit is bound to the window being closed.  If I remove the $run=0 I get an error about exiting the program with an additional thread running, so I'm pretty sure that's ending it.  Again, I believe my error is due to version limitations so I was looking to just hide it.  Thanks!

Comment: How are you shutting down Perl/TK?  Are you doing $mainwin->destroy or just exit?

Comment: I'm just using exit.  Would $mainwin->destroy help out?  I'll look into it in the meantime.

Comment: I have this problem, but it only seems to happen with Windows 7 and now Window XP. We're using the same ancient perl 5.8.8. and PerlTK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Suppress / Mute windows crash message box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940670/suppress-mute-windows-crash-message-box/17945422#17945422)  and add `use Win32API::File(); Win32API::File::SetErrorMode(2);`

Comment: Works with perl.5.8.8. It still prints "Segmentation Fault" from the command line, but if I run the perl script from a BAT file, no more error message. You get your 50 points :)

Answer (score -1):

This is a PERL issue, even if you $thread->detach, and the thread exits normally, you still get this error in some combinations of PERL/windows versions.

Nothing to worry about, just hide it.

Comment: How do you hide the "Perl Command Line Interpreter has stopped working" window from popping up?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question; please don't post it as an answer.

Comment: It is an answer, It is a windows PERL bug